# Crashlytics deprecating logException() what is the replacement?

Tags: android, deprecated, crashlytics

Anyone know the replacement call in Crashlytics for logException() which seems to be deprecated as of 2.2.4? My issue is that I have exceptions that I catch, but I suspect they lead to further errors which then cause the application to crash. I want to log all handled exceptions also, and see them in one place. Was using Flurry but just didn't seem to do the trick, where as Crashlytics looks to be more robust. I want them all in the same tool since it is a thousand times easier matching up the exceptions in just one place, rather than patching it together thru LogEntries, Flurry and Crashlytics. Once I get the major crash elements identified I will slowly remove the logException() calls and just look for real hard crashes.

thanks!

Comment: Where did u see it's deprecated? From the v2.2.4 [doc](http://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics/2.2.4/com/crashlytics/android/Crashlytics.html#logException(java.lang.Throwable)) it doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Yeah - my thought exactly! But inside of Eclipse it is marking as deprecated (it was not before the 2.2.4 upgrade I did today). But as you state, their documentation does not state that. I can only assume they are deprecating it because it is not supported in IOS? Or they are getting too much traffic?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here it is your : `Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(e);`

Comment: I think this is the actual answer :)

Comment: Is there any documentation that supports this (not trying to be sceptical, but I'm looking for documentation that will help me solve my bug)?

Answer (score 19):

After migration from fabric to firebase crashlytics...

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(e);
```

Answer (score 8):

Crashlytics got updated to 2.3.2. If you look at that [documentation](http://docs.fabric.io/javadocs/crashlytics/2.3.2/com/crashlytics/android/Crashlytics.html#logException(java.lang.Throwable)) it's deprecated. Check out the new exception method [here](https://dev.twitter.com/crashlytics/android/caught-exceptions)

Comment: Try not to link provide link only answers as links can break or their content change, instead provide the relevant code samples or content directly in your answer and link back to the source. I'll remove the downvote if you update your question

Answer (score 7):

Crashlytics documentation and Fabric.io documentation isn't very clear about this, so just to be clear:

- if you are compiling with `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.xxx@aar` or older, use this method:

  `Crashlytics.logException(e);`
- if you are using `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.3.xxx@aar`, use this method:

  `Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(e);`
- if you are using `com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.xxx@aar`, you can use any method:

  `Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(e);`
  `CrashlyticsCore.getInstance().logException(e);`

  `Crashlytics.logException(e);`

In conlusion: if you wish to rely on the [Fabric.io documentation](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html), check to make sure you are not compiling with crashlytics v2.3.xxx